# Create WiFi profile in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I've recently inherited a C# Windows 10 Mobile UWP app and now have a requirement to add functionality to be able to create and save a WiFi (EAP-SIM) connection profile so that when the user is within range of the network, connection is seamless.

From my research so far, I am coming up short on the APIs required do to this within the confines of UWP.

As time is now running short on the timeframe I have, I thought I'd ask here for any advise.  Any ideas/pointers, etc gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

> create and save a WiFi (EAP-SIM) connection profile

This kind of work belongs to Windows Device and Driver Technologies topic not app-based. It is out of UWP app scope.

Ref: [Wi-Fi information of Account provisioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/account-provisioning#BKMK_Contents_WiFi)

> This means the profile configures Windows to connect to an encrypted
>   network by using a SIM as the authentication type, such as a Hotspot
>   2.0 network. Hotspot 2.0 defines such a network to use WPA2-Enterprise with EAP-SIM authentication.

You will need to develop and add a driver to the OS on a mobile device by using a package. For more information you can reference [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/device-and-driver-technologies).